# regex to extract before colon and between quotes

Tags: regex, yaml

What regexp to use to match before colon and between quotes?

e.g
"This text only":"bla bla bla"
↓
This text only

I need this to extract only key fields in yaml.

Comment: Show some efforts of what you have already tried. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

`"(.*)"\:"(.*)"` shall provide you your both the key and value [test link](https://regex101.com/r/YFiQoj/1/)

If only the key is needed then:
`"(.*)".*` shall get you the key only part

Comment: This doesn't help.

Comment: (?<=  ")[^"]+(?=") regex resolved my query..thanks for your efforts